# remove redundant warning output message

Tags: python, warnings

When using the `warnings` module, the following code within a module:

```
import warnings
warnings.warn("User warning", Warning)
```

outputs the following:

```
/Users/aaragon/Desktop/test/__main__.py:23: Warning: User warning
  warnings.warn("User warning", Warning)
```

which I find redundant as somehow the code that produced the warning is output in the second line. Is there a way to output just the first line?

Interestingly, when using python3 interactively it gives me what I want:

```
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.warn("User warning", Warning)
__main__:1: Warning: User warning
```

I found in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/warnings.html) that one may use the `warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line=None)` function to do something like that?